# Check if text exists in Django template context variable

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

This may not be the best way of doing this (open to suggestions). But I want to display a button on my home page depending on the value of a Boolean in the custom user model.
I am passing the value of this boolean via context in the view. But I can't seem to get the template logic to work.

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default = False,)
    #more models...
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from accounts.models import CustomUser

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            adminStatus = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
            print(adminStatus.isAdmin)
            context['adminStatus'] = str(adminStatus.isAdmin)
            return context
```

**home page template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% block body %}

  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h4>Hi {{ user.username }}!</h4>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}" role="button"> Go to Dashboard</a>
  {% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in</p>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
  </div>
    {% if adminStatus == "True" %}
    <h1>test</h1>
    <div class = "adminPanel">
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'newEquipment' %}" role="button"> add new equipment</a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I can't see the "newEquipment" button even though the adminStatus context is equal to "True", as verified by the print() command.
I have a feeling my template logic is not correct. I also tried:

```
{% if adminStatus contains "True" %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view, `context['adminStatus']` is defined only when the user is logged in. Meanwhile in the template, you are checking for adminStatus when the user is *not* logged in.

First the `return context` statement needs to be un-indented once, so that context (with or without adminStatus) is available regardless:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        adminStatus = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        context['adminStatus'] = adminStatus.isAdmin
    return context
```

Next, yes you probably need to fix your template logic. Assuming you want to check for adminStatus only if the user is logged in, it should look like:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h4>Hi {{ user.username }}!</h4>
  ...
  {% if adminStatus %}
    <h1>test</h1>
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  ...
{% endif %}
```

---

**Original answer:**

In the view, you likely don't have to stringify `adminStatus.isAdmin`.

```
context['adminStatus'] = adminStatus.isAdmin
```

If passed to the context as a boolean, you should be able to use this expression in the template:

```
{% if adminStatus %}
```

Comment: Thanks @LionelW. I tried that first, then thought maybe it needs to be a string. That didn't work either. Not sure what is going on. I'm starting to wonder if it is because I have a nested if statement, not sure if there is a special way to handle this with template logic...

Comment: Yikes, rewrote my update for clarity; was rather off-base on what's important. Let us know how it goes.